# Should business/core deal with calling API of third party?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, clean-architecture

We have a business flow like this

1. Get list data from db
2. For each item in list
3. Convert item to JSON
4. Send data to the third party to get a result
5. Save result to db

`Send data` will be different based on third party, one requires using HTTP, one requires using FTP or gRPC call. I use an Interface to abstract the sending data to the third party and let API, an outside layer decide which method it wants to use.

The architecture follows the Clean Architect. We have Entity, Business/Core in the middle and wrapper by API and Infrastructure.

**Code example**

`In Business/Core project`

```
// Abstract class    
var items = await GetItemsAsync(args); // abstract method
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var json = await ConvertItemToJsonAsync(item); // abstract method
    var resultInString = await SendAsync(json); // abstract method
    await SaveResultAsync(item, resultInString); // abstract method
}

// Now for child classes, they will implement those abstract methods. 
// In this case, it will be

override Task<string> SendAsync(string json)
{
    return _thirdparty.SendDataAsync(json);
}

interface IThirdParty 
{ 
    Task<string> SendDataAsync(string json); 
}
```

It means child classes will accept an Interface called _thirdparty to decouple the send data to the third party. In API layer, it will easy to create some kinds of third parties such as sending by HTTP, FPT or gRPC and register DI or better a factory to use.

My care about Unit Test, when you write a unit test, you need a context, with the context, you know what is a unit to write a test case/script. 
For example, if we create a car, the context is a car that can be driven basically. Should we care about what kinds of the screw of the wheel is used? It is from suppliers' parts of assembly care. If we test each part of assembly, we need to care about the screw. That's is a context. If following the above way, I can easily write a unit-test for each abstract method and for a whole flow, I can create a mock Interface for third party.

But there is a problem for Business/Core, because the main point of this business is calling the third party, that is a context, the rest of the methods is dealing with db, which we don't need to test.

To make me can test flow in Business/Core, I need to move the concrete class of third party from API into Business/Core, then I can test it as an unit. By doing that, Business/Core now needs to use something called HttpClient, gRPC classes to work with third party.

My question is, should Business care about the network if it is its business? Or do we have any better way to solve it?

Comment: if I've not 100% misunderstood: why not define an interface for your abstraction layer in the business/core code, and then implement the abstraction layer elsewhere? Then the business/core layer doesn't need to care or know about HttpClient, gRPC, etc.

Comment: That's what I'm doing and it raises my question

Comment: Why does the business/core layer need to know or care about HttpClient, gRPC, etc. then?

Comment: because the main point of this business is calling the third party, that is a context. Please review again in my question, I provide all those info

Comment: "that is a context" - what does that mean?

Comment: I updated the question to provide what the context is

Comment: _"If we test each part of assembly, we need to care about the screw."_ - that's not a good analogy for unit testing. Business/core logic should be tested against the _interface_. For example, business logic has `SubmitOrder()` method. Does that call `SendDataAsync` in a mock of `IThirdParty`? Testing the actual implementation of `IThirdParty` is a completely separate issue.

Comment: I agree that we need to test against the interface, but please step back and think the business in this case if the data can not be sent to third party, the business is failed.

Comment: Does that call SendDataAsync in a mock of IThirdParty? It does

Comment: I think you're looking at this the wrong way. I'm not saying don't test the actual code that contacts the third party API. You can write integration tests for that, if you need to. I'm saying that all you need to test at the business layer is that it calls the right method on the interface correctly. Then you have a separate test to ensure that the real implementation of `IThirdParty` works correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207396/discussion-between-john-and-steve-lam).

Answer (score 1):

The question and (my) answer is opinionated.

If you build a system (or as your metaphor a car), you will need multiple layers of test. Unit test are the lowest lever of test and their main purpose is to test the implementation details of your *code*. They are part of the tooling and development cycle for developers *maintaining the code base*.

With that said; I don't think you should apply unit test on the "can the car drive" (those are more likely integration and regression tests), you should apply unit test on the "screws and bolts" level.

I think you should unit test your core logic even if *it only* calls third party APIs. I bet the order of things and error handling will be important in that code.

But like I said these are just my opinions.

But I guess that a future developer refactoring you code logic in a few years time will appreciate if the code have unit tests... and hence this future developer can be yourself.